# Solve for $x$ in $2^x-4^x > 0$

Tags: calculus

$2^x-4^x > 0$

I did:

$$2^x-4^x > 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow 2^x -2^{2x} > 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow -2^{2x} > -2^x \\
\Leftrightarrow 2^{2x} < 2^x \\
\Leftrightarrow 2x < x \\
\Leftrightarrow 2 < \frac{x}{x} \\
\Leftrightarrow 2 < 1$$

Then I tried a different approach starting on line 5:

$$2x < x \\
\Leftrightarrow x+x < x \\
\Leftrightarrow x < x-x \\
\Leftrightarrow x < 0$$

My question is, what did I do wrong in my first attempt?

Comment: When you multiply by a negative number, switch the direction of the inequality.

Comment: When dividing by $x$ you have assumed it is postive already. So what you got in first attemtp is that within the postiive real number, there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you go from $2x<x$ to $2<1$, you have to be careful. When you divide by $x$, and DON'T switch the direction of the inequality, you're assuming, that $x\neq0$ (because you divided) and that $x>0$ (because you didn't switch the inequality). Be careful when dividing in inequalities, because you may not know the sign of the variable that is dividing.